# "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" when parsing an array declared in a factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am building a basic app (with MEAN web frameworks and node webkit) in order to understand angularjs better.

Here is the content of my `notificationFactory.js`

```
function notificationFactory() {

    var fooMessages = [

        {
            id: 4,
            dismissable: true,
            name: "fooooBaaar",
            function: '',
            showInTopBar: false,
            priority: "high",
            icon: 'fooIconBarBarBar',
            topBarIcon: 'fooIconIconIcon'
        },

        {
            id: 3,
            dismissable: true,
            name: "foofooBarBar",
            function: '',
            showInTopBar: false,
            priority: "high",
            icon: 'fooIconfooIcon',
            topBarIcon: 'IconIconIcon'
        },

        {
            id: 2,
            dismissable: true,
            name: "foo foo",
            function: '',
            showInTopBar: false,
            priority: "high",
            icon: 'fooBaaaaaar',
            topBarIcon: 'IconFooIcon'
        },

        {
            id: 1,
            dismissable: true,
            name: "foo",
            function: '',
            showInTopBar: false,
            priority: "high",
            icon: 'fooIcon',
            topBarIcon: 'fooIconIcon'
        },
    ]

    fooMessages.TopBarDismiss = function (message) {
        $.each(fooMessages, function (i, v) {
            if(v.id = message.id) {
                fooMessages.splice(i,1);
            }
        });

    }

    return fooMessages;

}

angular.module('fooDemo').factory('notificationFactory', notificationFactory);
```

I call the `TopBarDismiss()` function in an HTML template using:

```
<div class="fooDismiss" ng-click="notificationFactory.TopBarDismiss(message)">Dismiss</div>
```

When I check out the console after pressing my Dismiss "button", I get this:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at notificationFactory.js:94
at Function.m.extend.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at Array.fooMessages.TopBarDismiss (notificationFactory.js:93)
at fb.functionCall (angular.js:10847)
at angular-touch.js:472
at k.$get.k.$eval (angular.js:12702)
at k.$get.k.$apply (angular.js:12800)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular-touch.js:471)
at angular.js:3097
at r (angular.js:325)angular.js:10072 (anonymous function)angular.js:7364 $getangular.js:12802 $get.k.$applyangular-touch.js:471 (anonymous function)angular.js:3097 (anonymous function)angular.js:325 rangular.js:3096 r.triggerHandlerangular.js:3111 S.(anonymous function)angular-touch.js:453 (anonymous function)angular.js:2853 (anonymous function)angular.js:325 rangular.js:2852 c
```

so it must be the

```
$.each(fooMessages, function (i, v) {
    if (v.id == message.id) {
    } 
});
```

part that is quite horrible.

Can you, guys, spot the error for me, please?

Comment: Offtopic: I don't think you should use $.each in your Factories/Controllers. Try to limit jQuery code to directives only, and use the supplied jQuery lib given to you by AngularJS. Ontopic: Can you supply us with a fiddle?

Comment: I tried it, it behaves the same as before, because every "message" had an "id"

Comment: why not `fooMessages.forEach(function(mes) { ... });`

Comment: Thanks, @Billy for the good practice advice.

Comment: add a debugger; statement at the beginning of the TopBarDismiss-function and check the value of the message-variable. I suspect ng-click="notificationFactory.TopBarDismiss(message)" doesn't pass you the correct object.

Comment: Try a console.log(message); I suspect that 'message' is undefined.
Also 'if(v.id = message.id) {' needs to be 'if(v.id === message.id) {'

Comment: So I changed the if condition: `if(message.id && v.id === message.id) {
                console.log("FooBar for the win");
                fooMessages.splice(i,1);
                console.log("FooBar for the weak");
            }`
The output is now `FooBar for the win
FooBar for the weak
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: @OmriAharon if I use `fooMessages.forEach(function(message)) { ... });` how can I splice the exact same message to get it out of my array?

Comment: @GeorgeNetu Didn't know you wanted to splice. For that I'd just do a regular for loop, but keep the Jquery out.

Comment: @OmriAharon I want to get that specific message out, if doesn't really matter what function do I use. I'm a beginner, so it's hard to keep track of every one of them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as said in the comments, you need to make sure the `message` object passed is really the one you're looking for.

Then, if you just want to splice you can do:

```
fooMessages.TopBarDismiss = function (message) {
        var index;
        for (var i = 0; i < fooMessages.length; i++) {
            if(fooMessages[i].id == message.id) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index) {
              fooMessages.splice(index,1);
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass `message` to the inner function. In that scope, `message` is `undefined`.